# How to make a query that filters out only back to back values that do not have any other values in-between?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Write a query that returns all urls involved in a "bounce."  A url X is involved in a bounce if a single user navigates from a page Y to page X, then immediately returns to page Y while visiting no other pages in between.   That is, you'll want to find two visits X->Y (on date d1) and Y->X (on date d2) for the same user u, for which there are no other visits by u between d1 and d2.**

You can compare dates just like numbers: d1 < d2 is true if date d1 is prior to date d2.

I self joined this table:

| url | dt | uid | src | rev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A04 | 1890-05-14 | A | A01 | 10 |
| A02 | 1890-05-15 | A | A04 | 15 |
| A01 | 1890-05-16 | A | A04 | 20 |

This is my query:

```
Select *
FROM Visit V1, Visit V2
WHERE V1.url = V2.src 
AND V1.src = V2.url
AND V1.dt < V2.dt
AND V1.uid = V2.uid
```

I understand that the single user and navigation part, and comparing the dates part.

A01 would not work here because the single user A nagivated from A01 -> A04 -> A01, however, the user visited A02 in between so it would return an empty set. How would I make it so that it return the urls only when the single user visits no other pages while navigating back and forth?

Comment: What do u mean by the exact join clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another condition in your where clause as below:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Visit visit WHERE visit.uid=V1.uid and visit.dt>V1.dt AND visit.dt<V2.dt)
```

Comment: This would filter out rows that do have back to back entries but do not look for values in between. But I am looking for urls which have no visits to pages in between so A02 would not work

Comment: Do you mean that you only want A02 to return back?  This is not what is stated in the question. Please clarify.

Comment: I don't want A02 to return back because the user visited another page. I would want A02 to return back if the user did not visit any other pages in between

Comment: According to your question, rows 1 and 3 would be an answer if A02 didn't existed. What you say is not what is stated in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that A01 would not work because the single user A nagivated from A01 -> A04 -> A01, however, the user visited A02 in between so it would return an empty set. How would I make it so that it return the urls only when the single user visits no other pages while navigating back and forth?

Comment: If you add the above line to your query, the response would be empty. If you don't, information for rows 1 and 3 would be returned back. If it's not like that, you have some other information contained in your table that affect the results.